# Button within react-router Link?

Tags: css, reactjs, button, react-router-dom

Say I have an element with the following structure:

```
<Link to={`/games/${game.id}`}>
  <GameInfo/>
  <CustomButton/>
</Link>
```

[image]

Is it possible for the button inside the link to behave independently from the link beneath **without using the `z-index` css property**? I'd like to do this while keeping the current behaviour in which hovering the button triggers both the hover effect for the button and for the link below.

Right now, if I click on the `Add to Library` button, the game gets added to the library but the Link below also gets triggered and the game profile page is open, which is not intended.

The only solution I can think of so far is something like this:

```
  <div> // <= move link hover effects here
    <Link to={`/games/${game.id}`}>
      <GameInfo/>
    </Link>

    <CustomButton/>
  </div>
```

But it's not ideal, because I would still like the area around the button to be part of the Link (so hover and the link itself work in the areas shown below).

[image]

Is `z-index` the only solution?

Comment: Have you tried preventing the default event actions and stopping event propagation in the button's `onClick` handler?

Comment: I'm wasn't familiar with propagation, it seems to be the key. After reading a bit on it, I have tried  adding `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` to the click handler function but it does not seem to do anything. Edit: I just noticed I'm getting a `Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined` error, let me check on that.

Comment: Can you create a simple reproducible demo in a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that we can examine and live debug in? There is event propagation, but z-index could be playing a part, overlays can also effect the "surface" that is being clicked, etc..

Comment: Solved it, passing the `event.stopPropagation()` to the inner button click handler instead of to the custom button component click handler made it work. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of preventDefault and stopPropagation to achieve this inside button click use like this below

```
<Link to="/game">
      <div>
      
        <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
           //function to do your stuff
          }}
        >
         Click Me
        </button>
      </div>
    </Link>
```

You can check the demo here

[https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-sun-dwnde?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-sun-dwnde?file=/src/home.js)